# tkinter value error : id must be a valid identifier returned from after or after_idle

Tags: python, tkinter, pyautogui

```
def start_quest(self):
    quest = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('quest.jpg', confidence = 0.9)
    if quest:
        pyautogui.click(quest[0] - 100, quest[1])
        self.after_cancel(self.loop)
    self.loop = self.after(1000, self.start_quest)
```

with tkinter gui,  I am trying to click the button if the `pyautogui` detects it. I used `self.after` to make the function to work until detection. However, the code returns an error:

> value error : id must be a valid identifier returned from after or after_idle

Also, because the `pyautogui` captures the window every seconds, the gui have buffering. How can I fix it?

Comment: put this `self.loop = self.after(1000, self.start_quest)` above of `if quest` and it works. the *alarm* isnt registerd to that point, so unknown.

Comment: How can I use after instead of time.sleep() ?

Comment: Have you examined `self.loop` immediately before calling `self.after_cancel(self.loop)`? I'm guessing the value is different from what you're assuming it is.

Comment: `self.after_cancel()` is not necessary and can be removed.  Then put `self.after(1000, self.start_quest)` in `else` block.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `self.loop` is not referring to the correct event id which returns by self.after

without showing the full code, it's hard to find what argument you are passing...!!